# Linq to DataTable not producing Distinct values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, linq-to-dataset

I have a datatable which has been dynamically generated from FoxPro tables using a UNION Select statement. e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM x UNION SELECT * FROM y UNION SELECT * FROM Z ORDER By v_alue1
```

This produces a datatable with about 100 rows, each containing many fields, one of which is c_olor. From this datatable, I would like to select the distinct colors and then output in a dropdown.

I have a public class Color which just has one property which I can then use as the DataTextField and DataValueField for the dropdownlist

```
Public Class Color
    Private _c_olor As String
    Public Property c_olor() As String
        Get
            Return _c_olor
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _c_olor = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

My linq statment is

```
Dim colorDs = (From o In dt.Rows Select Color = New With {.c_olor = o("c_olor").ToString().Trim(Nothing).ToLower()}).Distinct().ToList()
```

However this never results in the distinct colors.

I have searched and searched for what I am looking for, and this seems to be one of the methods to produce a distinct set of results, but this and the others do not work.

My reasoning behind getting the colors this way, is that I need to get various other distinct values from the same UNION SELECT datasource, so would just do one DB call, cache the results, and then just used this cached datasource to retrieve all my distinct values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a VB expert but it seems like you're creating your colors first and then trying to find the distinct colors

In this case, you need to implement Equals on your color class

Dim colorDs = (From o In dt.Rows Select Color = New With {.c_olor = o("c_olor").ToString().Trim(Nothing).ToLower()}).Distinct().ToList()

Alternatively, you could find disctinct values first and then create color instances

```
Dim colorDs = (From o In dt.Rows Select o("c_olor").ToString().Trim(Nothing).ToLower()).Distinct().ToList()
```

Should produce the list of unique string colors

Comment: Thanks. I just needed that extra approach to the problem. I found the distinct values from the data table, and then created the Color instances from that query.